# Get Path from another app (WhatsApp)

Tags: android, path, uri, whatsapp

I'm not getting Path from image or video from uri that I receive from whatsApp.

Uri comes like this: content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/16695

Media coming from Gallery, Downloads ands others are fine.

Anyone know how to get Path? This is the code I'm using:

```
public String getMediaPath(Context context, Uri uri) {

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                        ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                        ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                        ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                        ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                        ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                        ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
        );

    // DocumentProvider
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }


        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;

}

public String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                            String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String[] projection = {
            column[0]
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if (DEBUG)
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column[0]);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

The result of this log:

```
    if (DEBUG)
    Log.d(TAG + " File -",
            "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                    ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                    ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                    ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                    ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                    ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                    ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
    );
```

is this:

```
Authority: com.whatsapp.provider.media, Fragment: null, Port: -1, Query: null, Scheme: content, Host: com.whatsapp.provider.media, Segments: [item, 16348]
```

And the cursor on getDataColumn looks like this:

```
>>>>> Dumping cursor 
android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@1fc81ac
I/System.out: 0 {
I/System.out: }
I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this it will help for you.You can't get path from WhatsApp directly.If you need an file path first copy file and send new file path.
Using the code below

```
 public static String getFilePathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String fileName = getFileName(contentUri);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
        File copyFile = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH  + fileName+".jpg");
        copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
        return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) return null;
    String fileName = null;
    String path = uri.getPath();
    int cut = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1) {
        fileName = path.substring(cut + 1);
    }
    return fileName;
}

public static void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
        if (inputStream == null) return;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then IOUtils class is like below

```
public class IOUtils {



private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 2;

private IOUtils() {
    // Utility class.
}

public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Exception, IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input, BUFFER_SIZE);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(output, BUFFER_SIZE);
    int count = 0, n = 0;
    try {
        while ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        out.flush();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.toString());
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.toString());
        }
    }
    return count;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to this , then you get a bitmap of selected image and then you can easily find it's native path from Device Default Gallery.

```
Bitmap roughBitmap= null;
    try {
    // Works with content://, file://, or android.resource:// URIs
    InputStream inputStream =
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    roughBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

    // calc exact destination size
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, roughBitmap.Width, roughBitmap.Height);
    RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
    m.SetRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.Center);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.GetValues(values);


    // resize bitmap if needed
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(roughBitmap, (int) (roughBitmap.Width * values[0]), (int) (roughBitmap.Height * values[4]), true);

    string name = "IMG_" + new Java.Text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").Format(new Java.Util.Date()) + ".png";
    var sdCardPath= Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("DCIM").AbsolutePath;
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(sdCardPath);
    if (!file.Exists())
    {
        file.Mkdir();
    }
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, name);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Inform the user that things have gone horribly wrong
    }
```

Comment: I got the bitmap, but how can i get the path form it

Comment: @Eduardo Bonfa , after getting bitmap you can convert it to file and get path of this file.i was edited answer

Comment: this works with images, any idea to work other medias too?

Comment: This doesn't work. `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` throws exception. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578918/android-getting-image-bitmap-from-third-party-app-e-g-whatsapp-via-content) question please.

Comment: @Atul , which type of exception throws ?

Comment: @dharam: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.whatsapp.MediaProvider from ProcessRecord{a4b804a 30321:com.myapp/u0a145} (pid=30321, uid=10145) that is not exported from uid 10083` Please check more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578918/android-getting-image-bitmap-from-third-party-app-e-g-whatsapp-via-content)

Comment: @dharam I'm facing same issue. Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a path to file from WhatsApp. They don't expose it now. The only thing you can get is `InputStream`:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/16695"));
```

Using `is` you can show a picture from WhatsApp in your app.

Comment: This does not work. `OpenInputStream` throws exception. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578918/android-getting-image-bitmap-from-third-party-app-e-g-whatsapp-via-content) question please.

Comment: I have checked this on my LG Stylus 3 (Android 7.0) and it solves the problem. Did you try on yours phone?

Comment: Yes on Marshmallow. Please note this exception is happening since WhatsApp rolled out their latest updated version. Previously it was working fine (I think they were simply sharing image file path `file://`) but now they sharing using `content://`

Comment: I am not sure about last version of WhatsApp, but I have checked that the Uri has a scheme `content` - it was a `"content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/xxxxx"`. I will chech it on Marshmallow.

Comment: Okay I found the problem. We need to call `openInputStream` from the initial activity itself which gets launched after we share image from WhatsApp. I was storing URI in initial activity and was calling `openInputStream` from another activity. That throws exception.

Comment: It throws Security exception though I'm using Uri in the same activity which is launching.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the URI to file and then to bytes if you want to upload the photo to your server.

> Check out :  https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/49575321

Answer (score 0):

Using the code example below will return to you the bitmap :

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/128752")))
```

After that you all know what you have to do.

Comment: question is to get file path from Uri and not to convert a file path to uri

Answer (score 0):

It works for me for opening small text file... I didn't try in other file

```
protected void viewhelper(Intent intent) {
    Uri a = intent.getData();
    if (!a.toString().startsWith("content:")) {
        return;
    }
    //Ok Let's do it
    String content = readUri(a);
    //do something with this content
}
```

here is the readUri(Uri uri) method

```
private String readUri(Uri uri) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int result;
            String content = "";
            while ((result = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                content = content.concat(new String(buffer, 0, result));
            }
            return content;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("receiver", "IOException when reading uri", e);
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("receiver", "IOException when closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I got it from this repository https://github.com/zhutq/android-file-provider-demo/blob/master/FileReceiver/app/src/main/java/com/demo/filereceiver/MainActivity.java
I modified some code so that it work.

Manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You need to add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*
     *    Your OnCreate
     */
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    //VIEW"
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {
        viewhelper(intent); // Handle text being sent
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*
     *    Your OnCreate
     */
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

```
//VIEW"
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {viewhekper(intent);//Handle text being sent}
```

Comment: Can you describe why this code is the solution instead of just posting the code?