# How to Get Image Path in my App which is Selected from Whats app's Chat?

Tags: java, android, .net, android-intent

i have demo application with image view and in this image view i need to set image from which selected from *whats app* Chat,
Currently i was getting Path of selected image i.e. *content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/245429*

Does any idea to resolve this ?
Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no image path, as there is no requirement that this `Uri` point to a file, let alone point to a file that you have direct filesystem access to.

Use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) and provide it the `Uri` that you get from WhatsApp. Those libraries know how to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the bytes associated with that content, convert those bytes into a `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`, and put the `Bitmap` into your `ImageView`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion,  i have already tried with **Picasso** , but that not and Throw Exception "File Not Found",is there any way to Get Native Image Path From Gallery ,which one file Selected in Whats App Live Chat,
or Identify Selected image from Device Gallery and it's Path

Comment: @dharam: "but that not and Throw Exception "File Not Found"" -- then ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing your code and the complete Java stack trace of the error. "is there any way to Get Native Image Path From Gallery" -- no.

Comment: Please Check
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465601/get-path-from-another-app-whatsapp)

same issue occur with me.

Comment: this was perfect work in **Gmail** , i.e. first you select an image from your chat in whats app and then share it with gmail, it can be easily show there,but same thing in my app i am geeting encoded path from whats app.

Comment: @dharam: The answer on the question that you linked to shows the same solution that I suggested: use `openInputStream()`. If you are having problems with that, as I wrote, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing your code and the complete Java stack trace of the error.

Comment: @dharam Pl share ur solution here!