# Unable to get the image path from whatsapp share URI

Tags: android, image, uri, media, whatsapp

```
Uri = content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/118727
```

I'm not able to get the actual path from this URI

Comment: image path? what do you need it for? if for `ImageView`, then simply use `setImageURI` method

Comment: i need to upload into server

Comment: so you dont need any path, what you need is `InputStream` - see `ContentResolver` API docs on how to get one

Comment: Ohh. will try it and revert u. Thanks..

Comment: it will download the image again and upload??

Comment: yes its already downloaded.. i have to send it as multipart file. so from InputStream can i send?

Comment: Could you show us how you get that URI?

Comment: sharing pic from whatsapp to my application.

Comment: How is it possible to share a picture from whatsapp?

Comment: Go to your whatsapp chat -- click any image -- click on 3 dots -- click on share.

Comment: This is what I found Get real [URI file](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-real-file-path-from-android-uri/)

Answer (score 4):

Following the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) ,  i receive the image intent through :

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } 
}
```

ContentResolver wasn't working in this case as "_data" field was returning null. So i found another way to get a file from content URI.

In **handleSendImage()** you need to open inputStream and then copy it into a file.

```
void handleSendImage(Intent intent) throws IOException {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
      File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "image");
      InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
      try {

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
          int read;

          while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
          }

          output.flush();
        } finally {
          output.close();
        }
      } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        byte[] bytes =getFileFromPath(file);
        //Upload Bytes.
      }
    }
  }
```

**getFileFromPath()** gets you the bytes which you can upload on your server.

```
  public static byte[] getFileFromPath(File file) {
    int size = (int) file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    try {
      BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
      buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
      buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bytes;
  }
```

Comment: @Suseendran Kandasamy : Did you try this one ?

Comment: i want to know something, how can i know the extension of the old file after getting it from contentResolver? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get **imageFilePath** from **getRealPathFromUri()** below:

```
String filePath = getRealPathFromUri(this, fileUri);

   // You can upload it as File 
   if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
        // Using Retrofit you can do it like

        // create Retrofit Client code......

        // creates RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual filename
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

       // pass body as parameter while execute call

       }
   }
```

> **getRealPathFromUri()**

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Comment: Its not working for whatsapp content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/118727